# Error al insertar un cliente desde java a una base de datos en SqlServer

Tags: java

Hola a toda esta gran comunidad, me he topado con un problema estoy realizando un sistema en JAVA el cual esta conectado con una Base de Datos en SqlServer y cuando corro el formulario para registrar un clientes me manda el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si algo anda mal en mi código o a la hora de haber hecho la base de datos tuve un error, también les cuento que en mi base de datos estoy usando Generalización de la tabla persona heredando los atributos a la tabla cliente y trabajador, he puesto como clave principal **idpersona** en la tabla persona, al igual he puesto este mismo atributo como clave principal en las tablas cliente y trabajador.

Les dejo parte del diagrama E-R de mi base de datos en SqlServer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se porque me manda este error si alguien me ayuda a resolverlo se lo estaré agradecido de antemano.

Gracias Hasta pronto...

Comment: El mensaje parece indicar que estás intentando insertar un trabajador en la tabla `trabajador` pero al haber declarado la col. `idpersona` de dicha tabla llave foránea de la tabla `persona`, el `idpersona` que se crea en la tabla `trabajador` no existe en la tabla `persona` y de ahí el error. Si has diseñado las tablas así el punto de inserción de datos debería ser la tabla `persona` y a partir de esa persona existente modificar todo lo que haga falta en la tabla `trabajador`. Si tú empiezas a insertar datos en la tabla `trabajador` sin contar con lo que hay en `persona` vas a tener problemas

Comment: Ese modelo es malo.. una persona es cliente, o trabajador.. la que reserva es la persona, no el cliente o el trabajador. el modelo esta mal.

Comment: Y no pegues una imagen de tu error, pega el error. copialo de alguna forma y muestralo en la pregunta.

Comment: El modelo no tiene por que ser malo en sí @gbianchi, eso depende... puede haber personas que no sean trabajadores, o que no sean clientes... lo que no puede haber es trabajadores o clientes que no sean personas. Aquí, me parece a mí, la cuestión es que el punto de entrada debería ser siempre la tabla `persona`, no se puede ir a insertar directamente en la tabla `trabajador`.

Comment: @A.Cedano la personas son el punto de entrada. y las que hacen reservas son personas con el atributo clientes. lo que ves ahi es un modelo totalmente circular. No es correcto, y si la persona no es ni trabajador ni cliente es muy probable que no pertenezca al sistema. Mas alla del error que es claro, podrias explicar como es que fue pensado ese modelo?

Comment: Bueno primeramente gracias por las respuestas, el modelo fue creado utilizando una tabla como padre llamada persona con todos los atributos de persona, las cuales serán heredadas a las tablas hijas cliente y trabajador, estas tablas heredan todos los atributos de la tabla padre persona, agregando los atributos propios de la tabla cliente y trabajador. Tengo entendido que a eso se le llama generalización en base de datos. Lo que no se si hice bien fue poner la misma clave principal de la tabla persona, en las tablas hijas cliente y trabajador.

Comment: Ahora el sistema me esta dejando insertar el cliente pero solo se me guardan los datos de la tabla persona, pero los datos de la tabla cliente me aparecen NULL, tanto el idpersona, como el codigo_cliente. Mi pregunta es porqué no me guarda los datos en la tabla cliente.